# Replace Text in Div using contains(match)

Tags: jquery

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/WM6wG/

I'm trying to replace a text in a div, but cannot seem to figure out why it's not working.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="text">abc</div>
<div class="text">foo</div>
<div class="text">bar</div>
```

*jQuery:*

```
var match = 'abc';
if ($('div.text:contains(match)')) {
    $('div.text').html(function(){
        $(this).replaceText(match, 'xyz');
    }
}
```

Ideally the expected output should be: `xyz foo bar` but it remains `abc foo bar`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `'div.text:contains(' + match + ')'` provided you have `replaceText` plugin included

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You are searching for "match" rather than the value of the variable `match`.
2. Your `if` statement is pointless as you have a fresh selector for `div.text` on the next line. So if one of the elements matches, your code will run this against all matching elements anyway.
3. Your `html()` method is not returning anything.
4. `replaceText()` is not a standard function. Unless this is a custom function you have made, or you are using the [replaceText() plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/), replace it with `replace()`

---

```
var match = 'abc';
$("div.text:contains(" + match + ")").each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
    $this.html(function(){
        return $this.html().replace(match, "xyz");
    });
});
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wh7xn/*

---

If there are multiple instance of "abc" you wish to replace, use RegEx:

```
var match = 'abc';
var re = new RegExp(match,"g");
$("div.text:contains(" + match + ")").each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
    $this.html(function(){
        return $this.html().replace(re, "xyz");
    });
});
```

***Live Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/wh7xn/2/*

Comment: What about multiple instances of `abc` contained within the same div?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `$('div.text:contains(match)')` you are searching for a div containing the literal string 'match'.

You could do it like this: `$('div.text:contains(' + match + ')')`

Just be careful that the variable match doesn't containing anything of significance to the jquery selector such as a `)`.

Answer (score 1):

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WM6wG/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var match = 'abc';
    if ($('div.text:contains('+match+')')) {
        $('div.text').html(function(){
            $(this).replaceText(match, 'xyz');
        });
    }
});
```

2 things!

1. The `'('+match+')'`
2. You forgot a parenthesis after the function to close the html call.
3. The js file for the function replaceText (@Jasen thank you!)

Comment: 3. jquery.ba-replacetext.js

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it all in one line (not counting your var declaration):

```
var match = 'abc';
$('div.text:contains(' + match + ')').text($('div.text:contains(' + match + ')').text().replace(match, 'xyz'));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WM6wG/4/)**

No if statement needed and `replace` instead of `replaceText`.

If you'll have multiple matches, use this:

```
var match = 'abc';
$('div.text:contains(' + match + ')').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(match, 'xyz'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WM6wG/5/)**

Comment: What about multiple instances of `abc` contained within the same div?